# Groovy memoized annotation protectedCacheSize usage

Tags: groovy

When reading the document I'm curious why the @Memoized have these 2nd parameter. What is the use case? When is the relation between the garbage collection and cache replace behavior?

```
int protectedCacheSize: Number of cached return values to protect from garbage collection.
```

[Groovy memoized protectedCacheSize](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/transform/Memoized.html#protectedCacheSize())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#xform-Memoized) mentions:

> By default, the size of the cache is unlimited and no cache result is protected from garbage collection.
>
> Setting a protectedCacheSize>0 would create an unlimited cache with some results protected.
>
> Setting maxCacheSize>0 would create a limited cache but without any protection from garbage protection.
>
> Setting both would create a limited, protected cache.

So a use case would be if you e.g. have a memory intensive application that might run the risk of the cache being garbage collected too often or deeply, then using the `protectedCacheSize` can forcibly protect a certain number of  the most recently used cache entries from garbage collection.

This will make even more sense if the cached values are expensive to compute and the `protectedCacheSize` is not too high as to prevent the GC from regaining needed memory.

Digging a bit deeper the AST for the `@Memoized` [annotation](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/01309f9d4be34ddf93c4a9943b5a97843bff6181/src/main/groovy/transform/Memoized.java#L94) is handled by the [groovy.transform.MemoizedASTTransformation.java](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/01309f9d4be34ddf93c4a9943b5a97843bff6181/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/transform/MemoizedASTTransformation.java#L154) which converts the method call to a `Closure`.

Depending on the max and protected args being 0 or not different `memoize` methods are then called on the  Closure, see the [implementation](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/01309f9d4be34ddf93c4a9943b5a97843bff6181/src/main/groovy/lang/Closure.java#L703) for more detail (scroll down for the three other memoize methods).